# Conditional fields in a ModelForm.Meta

Tags: python, django

Assume we have a custom user model in a Django application. In order to make it CRUDable from the admin page, we want to define some forms.

Below is the `UserChangeForm` used to modify an instance of our custom user model

```
class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model  = MyCustomUser
        fields = (
            ...,
            'email',
            'is_active',
            'is_admin',
            'groups',
            ....
        )
```

The question is: **how do I implement a *conditional* `fields` in the `Meta` class based on the model instance (i.e., out of scope for Meta)?**

The goal is to declare something like

```
def get_fields(self):
    if self.instance.is_company:
        return ('email', 'company_name', 'headquarters')
    else:
       return ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```

in the outer class, then find a way to inject the result of the function in `Meta.fields`. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can delete fields from the form in the `__init__()` constructor:

```
class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        fields = ('email', 'company_name', 'headquarters',
                           'first_name', 'last_name', )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.is_company:
            fields_to_delete = ('first_name', 'last_name')
        else:
            fields_to_delete = ('company_name', 'headquarters')
        for field in fields_to_delete:
            del self.fields[field]
```

Comment: Nicely done. By the way do you have a link that explains how those `Meta` classes work behind the scene? I am surprised that we only need to do a `self.fields` in order to access the fields (and not `self.Meta.fields` as I would expect).

Comment: Forms API for `fields`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/api/#accessing-the-fields-from-the-form

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Django admin, you can use the [`ModelAdmin.get_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_fields) method.

```
class UserModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    def get_fields(request, obj=None):
        if obj is None:
            return ('email', ...) # suitable list of fields for adding object
        elif obj.is_company:
            return ('email', 'company_name', 'headquarters')
        else:
            return ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
```