# Django: what script function will reload the modelform after onchange?

Tags: javascript, html, django, modelform

What script function will trigger a reload of the modelform after a onchange event in a dropdown?

Below, I am using 'product_type' as a drop down choice field. I have given it css_id='selector'

The modelform contains a conditional script based upon this selector (from post [Conditional fields in a ModelForm.Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988814/conditional-fields-in-a-modelform-meta))

The form changes given the choice and therefore I would need to update/reload to reflect the choice made in the drop-down. Which script function will do the trick in this case?

in my html,

```
<script>

$("#selector").on("change", function() {..???.});

</script>
```

Code:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = AllProduct
        fields = ('__all__')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-4'
        self.helper.form_id = 'All-product'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.helper.form_action = ('submit_form')
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit', css_class='btn-success'))

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('product_type', css_class='form-control', css_id='selector'),
            Field('car_make', css_class='select2'),
            Field('boat_make', css_class='select2'),
            Field('number_wheels', step=1, min=0),
            Field('number_sails', step=1, min=0),
             )


        product = 'product_type'

        if product == 'Car':
            fields_to_delete = ('boat_make', 'number_sails')
        else:
            fields_to_delete = ('car_make', 'number_wheels')
        for field in fields_to_delete:
            del self.fields[field]
```

Comment: You can use `ajax ` request to get updated value.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, however, a general type of answer does not help me. I have spent several days trying to figure it out by searching forums and asking here is my very last resort. What I am kindly asking for is a more hands-on answer that works, ie, a more workable answer. Such building block I can later build further upon. I am genuinely stuck at the moment and need some kind help getting out of it to be able to continue. Thanks.

Comment: Suppose you create a function based view for ajax request. Than when drop down changed you pass the product-type to your view and make your logic there like initialize your `ProductForm` and pass the args to `ProductForm`. Then get the value from `ProductForm` and return the form. Then Update your view by JavaScript by accessing each form field.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and suggestion, I will look further into it. As I am using Django, I had hopes there existed a quicker "built-in" solution with just a single line of code to make it work, such as 
$("#selector").on("change", function() { update }); or similar

Comment: I didn't see any function until today.